# How to do a narrow to wide transformation of data when there are no key names

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, window-functions

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
school_id | class_id | recess_num | student_id
----------------------------------------------
27        | 6        | 2          | 12
27        | 6        | 2          | 53
27        | 6        | 2          | 23
27        | 6        | 2          | 47
27        | 14       | 2          | 6
27        | 14       | 2          | 51
27        | 14       | 2          | 42
27        | 14       | 2          | 60
```

The idea is that certain students from different classes go out for recess at the same time. A couple of important points:

- The same number of students from each class go out at the same time
- The number of students from each class that go out each time is always the same (let's say 4 at a time)

I would like to create a wide table representation of this data where all the students that are out at each recess are captured in a single row. Since the number of students is always the same, I want to create new columns for each of the students:

```
school_id | class_id | recess_num | student_1 | student_2 | student_3 | student_4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27        | 6        | 2          | 12        | 53        | 23        | 47
27        | 14       | 2          | 6         | 51        | 42        | 60
```

What is the best way to accomplish this using only a SQL query?

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    school_id,
    class_id,
    recess_num,
    max(case when rn = 1 then student_id end) student_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then student_id end) student_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then student_id end) student_3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then student_id end) student_4
from (
    select
        t.*, 
        row_number() 
            over(partition by school_id, class_id, recess_num order by student_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
    group by 
    school_id,
    class_id,
    recess_num
```

The inner query ranks students within groups of school/class/recess, ordered by increasing id. Then the outer query pivots the data, using conditional aggregation.

Note that this does not produces exactly the same ordering of students in the columns as your expected result. However, this seems like a more consistent method to order the students by id (your expected result does not seem consistent in that regard).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddecf786493307ad6ecb6c24ab19db17)**:

```
school_id | class_id | recess_num | student_1 | student_2 | student_3 | student_4
--------: | -------: | ---------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
       27 |        6 |          2 |        12 |        23 |        47 |        53
       27 |       14 |          2 |         6 |        42 |        51 |        60
```

Comment: can use rank if there are multiple with same studentids

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    school_id, 
    class_id, 
    recess_num, 
    case when student_id=12 then student_id end as student1,
    case when student_id=53 then student_id end as student2,
    case when student_id=23 then student_id end as student3,
    case when student_id=47 then student_id end as student4,
from table 
group by 
    school_id, 
    class_id, 
    recess_num
```

Comment: I need something more general than this, I want to do it for all `class_id`s, and the example I gave is only a tiny subset of the data

Comment: This is general for all class ids as if ypu cpuld see in group by apart from student ids other columns are listed as general. If your database supports pivot can use that as pivot is used to convert rows to columns. If not then you could use either of the 2 answerd posted above. In the above answer if you are sure thatvthe studentids would be atmost 4 or less with those values mentioned then can use the above else if youbhave a lot of values with data not known then use the other its your choice